# The best way to access data from a database every X seconds (asynchronously)

Tags: php, database, asynchronous

Ok, I didn't really now how to formulate this question, and especially not the title. But i'll give it a try and hope i'm being specific enough while trying to keep it relevant to others.

I you want to run a php script in the background (via ajax) every X seconds that returns data from a database, how do you do this the best way without using to much of the server resources?

My solution looks like this:

A user visits a webpage, ever x seconds that page runs a javascript. The javascript calls a PHP script/file that calls the database, retrieves the data and returns the data to the javascript. The javascript then prints the data to the page. My fear is that this way of solving it will put a lot of pressure on the server if there is a lot (10 000) simultaneous visitors on the page. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like the best way, given the spec/requirement you set out.

Another way is to have an intermediary step. If you are going to have a **huge** amount of traffic (otherwise this does not introduce any benefit, but to the contrary may overcomplicat/slow the process), add another table that records the last time a dataset was pulled, and a hard file (say, XML) which if the 'last time' was deemed too long ago, is created from a new query, this XML then feeds the result returned to the user.

So:

1.Javascript calls PHP script (AJAX)

2.PHP pings DB table which contains last time data was fully output

3.If time is too great, 'main' query is rerun and XML file is regenerated from output
ELSE skip to 4

4.Fetch the XML file and output as appropriate for returned AJAX

Comment: So it's better to fetch data from an XML file than the database?

Comment: It depends on your need- at some point the XML file will need to be created from the DB. DB is the best bet for 'live' requests, having a static XML file to service requests, a file that is still fed from the DB but updated every so often, reduces DB load. It really revolves around your config

Comment: I don't really now what an intermediary step mean. But is it better to run a cron action every x seconds that prints the result to an XML file? You're to fast for me :)

Comment: If you have high traffic which you think you may not have the bandwidth for, that would be a good way to do it :) think of it as a throttle

Comment: Wouldn't it be a problem if the XML file is altered (updated by the cron action) at the same time as it's being read from?

Comment: I wouldn't use XML as a cache mechanism, it will actually result in worse performance. If you are worried about high loads you should look into proper caching systems which save on memory. Memcache and Redis are popular options. But I still think this is over engineering if you're just starting.

Comment: @Joakim, you can use flock to control this, @pablasso, indeed, hence the stress on the fact it is only appropriate in certain situations (i.e if you didnt want to exploit mem caching) at the end of the day it all depends on data size + request frequency = overhead

Comment: It sounds a little bit to advanced for me. Maybe i'll try the Comet technique.

Comment: Dont forget, you may be OK just carrying on the way you are - is it likely you'll be getting a vast amount of requests? Regular DB querying may be fine

Comment: The server must be able to handle 10 000 simultaneous users. Maybe it's best to skip the asynchronous function..

Answer (score 1):

You can do it the other way, contacting the client just when you need it and wasting less resources.

[Comet](http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start) it's the way to go for this option:

> Comet is a programming technique that
>   enables web servers to send data to
>   the client without having any need for
>   the client to request it. This
>   technique will produce more responsive
>   applications than classic AJAX. In
>   classic AJAX applications, web browser
>   (client) cannot be notified in real
>   time that the server data model has
>   changed. The user must create a
>   request (for example by clicking on a
>   link) or a periodic AJAX request must
>   happen in order to get new data fro
>   the server.

Comment: That solves one part of it, yes; but there still needs to be a server-side process which will check if the data has changed in the database.

Comment: You don't need that. The same processes who change the database will trigger the requests to the users.